# Getting value from ComboBox

Tags: c#

This is my code

```
string key = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)ComboBox1.SelectedItem).Key;
string value = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)ComboBox1.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Exception: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Your code is valid, provided that you added a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` to the combobox in the first place.

Comment: How is the combo box populated? The code for this is needed before your question can be answered.

Comment: im assuming you are doing this casting while posting data back to server. Can you please post the code in which you are sending the data to View?

Comment: while you are debugging what is data you are having in the key ?

Comment: Load Combobox : try
            {
                OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ComboBox1.DisplayMember="Text";
                ComboBox1.ValueMember="Value";

                ComboBox1.Items.Add(new {Text="Select",Value="aa"});

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    ComboBox1.Items.Add(new { Text = dr[0].ToString().Trim(), Value = dr[1].ToString().Trim() });
                }
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bind to combobox:**

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    dict.Add((i).ToString(), String.Format("Item {0}", i));
}
ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
ComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

**Get value:**

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)ComboBox.SelectedItem;

foreach(KeyValuePair k in kvp)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", k.Key, k.Value);
}
```